# Spring Data Reactive MongoDB + QueryDSL - MongoDB Driver version issue - Method did not exist : com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.getDescription

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux, querydsl

Here is my pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.12.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>${reactor.kafka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm unable to start the Spring boot application because of the below error:

```
"ERROR","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter","message":"\n\n***************************\nAPPLICATION FAILED TO START\n***************************\n\nDescription:\n\nAn attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:\n\n    com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.createCluster(DefaultClusterFactory.java:182)\n\nThe following method did not exist:\n\n    'java.lang.String com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings.getDescription()'\n\nThe calling method's class, com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory, was loaded from the following location:\n\n    jar:file:/Users/rahulraj/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.8/mongo-java-driver-3.12.8.jar!/com/mongodb/connection/DefaultClusterFactory.class\n\nThe called method's class, com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings, is available from the following locations:\n\n    jar:file:/Users/rahulraj/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.6.1/mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar!/com/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings.class\n    jar:file:/Users/rahulraj/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.8/mongo-java-driver-3.12.8.jar!/com/mongodb/connection/ClusterSettings.class\n\nThe called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:\n\n    com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings: 

file:/Users/rahulraj/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.6.1/mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar\n\n\nAction:\n\nCorrect the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory and com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings
```

I tried to print the dependency tree and here it is:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-r2dbc:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-relational:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-r2dbc:jar:5.3.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.r2dbc:r2dbc-spi:jar:0.9.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.r2dbc:r2dbc-pool:jar:0.9.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-pool:jar:0.2.10:compile
[INFO] +- io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql:jar:0.8.12.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.ongres.scram:client:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- com.ongres.scram:common:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- com.ongres.stringprep:saslprep:jar:1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |        \- com.ongres.stringprep:stringprep:jar:1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.24:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:1.0.24:runtime
[INFO] |     +- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.24:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.24:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.84.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.projectreactor.netty.incubator:reactor-netty-incubator-quic:jar:0.0.13:runtime
[INFO] |     |  \- io.netty.incubator:netty-incubator-codec-native-quic:jar:linux-x86_64:0.0.33.Final:runtime
[INFO] |     |     \- io.netty.incubator:netty-incubator-codec-classes-quic:jar:0.0.33.Final:runtime
[INFO] |     |        \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:runtime
[INFO] |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http-brave:jar:1.0.24:runtime
[INFO] |        \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-http:jar:5.14.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.3.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.5.0-4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.8.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.8.4:runtime
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-reactivestreams:jar:4.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mongodb:bson:jar:4.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:4.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.mongodb:bson-record-codec:jar:4.6.1:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] +- io.projectreactor.kafka:reactor-kafka:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:jar:5.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:jar:5.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.23:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.23:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:jar:5.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.22:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO] +- com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:3.12.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.querydsl:querydsl-core:jar:5.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.mysema.commons:mysema-commons-lang:jar:0.2.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.querydsl:querydsl-codegen:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] |     +- com.querydsl:codegen-utils:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] |     |  \- org.eclipse.jdt:ecj:jar:3.26.0:provided
[INFO] |     +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
[INFO] |     \- io.github.classgraph:classgraph:jar:4.8.108:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.23:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.3.23:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.7.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.7.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.5:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.22.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.18:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.18:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.23:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] +- io.projectreactor:reactor-test:jar:3.4.24:test
[INFO] +- io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:jar:1.9.5:runtime
[INFO] |  \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_common:jar:0.15.0:runtime
[INFO] |     \- io.prometheus:simpleclient:jar:0.15.0:runtime
[INFO] |        +- io.prometheus:simpleclient_tracer_otel:jar:0.15.0:runtime
[INFO] |        |  \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_tracer_common:jar:0.15.0:runtime
[INFO] |        \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_tracer_otel_agent:jar:0.15.0:runtime
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.24:compile
[INFO] \- net.apmoller.crb.ohm.logger:ohm-logger:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.68:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.68:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.68:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.23:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.68:compile
[INFO]    |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.68:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-api:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-brave:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-context-slf4j:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-messaging:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-rpc:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-spring-rabbit:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-kafka-streams:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-httpclient:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-httpasyncclient:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-jms:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-mongodb:jar:5.13.7:compile
[INFO]    |     +- io.zipkin.aws:brave-propagation-aws:jar:0.21.3:compile
[INFO]    |     \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-metrics-micrometer:jar:2.16.3:compile
[INFO]    |        \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.16.3:compile
[INFO]    |           \- io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:jar:2.23.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO]    +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO]    |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO]    +- ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-json-classic:jar:0.1.5:compile
[INFO]    |  \- ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-json-core:jar:0.1.5:compile
[INFO]    +- ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-jackson:jar:0.1.5:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO]    +- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:7.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.4.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.11.1:compile
[INFO]       \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.21:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I'm pretty much sure that the issue is with the conflicting MongoDB driver versions in `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive` and `querydsl-mongodb`. One with `mongo-java-driver-3.12.8.jar` and another with `mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar`.

How can I mention java driver that works for both (basically overriding the conflicting version) in pom.xml ? I tried to explicitly mention `mongodb-java`/`mongodb-core` driver in pom.xml, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue by excluding the java driver from `querydsl-mongodb` dependency:

```
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
          <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```